# Bang-bang Solution to Optimization Problem on the Sphere

Tags: calculus, polynomials, optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

For $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$ define
$P(z) = \sum_{i=1}^n z^i x_i y_i$.
I want to minimize the function
$$
\frac{1-P(z)^2}{P'(z)^2}
=\frac{1-(\sum_{i=1}^n z^{i} x_i y_i)^2}{(\sum_{i=1}^n i z^{i-1} x_i y_i)^2}
$$
for a given $z\in[-1,1]$ over all $x$ and $y$ restricted by $\|x\|_2=\|y\|_2=1$.

Conjecture: For any $z\in[-1,1]$ there is some $i\in[1,n]$, such that the optimal solution is to put all the weight of $x$ and $y$ on some $i$.
That is, let $x_i=y_i=\pm 1$, and put $0$ on the remaining coordinates.
I believe this is known as a ''bang-bang'' solution.

---

I can prove the conjecture for $z$ close to $0$:
Using a Taylor expansion
$$
\frac{1-P(z)^2}{P'(z)^2}
=\frac{1-P(0)^2}{P'(0)^2} + O(z)
=\frac{1}{(x_1y_1)^2} + O(z),
$$
it's clear that in the case $z=0$ we should put all the weight on the first two coordinates.

Numerically I have verified the conjecture for many other choices of $z$ and $n$, but I barely know where to start for the proof.

**Update:**
By the suggestion of Michael Grant we can define
$$
f_z(w) = \sum_{i=1}^n z^i w[i]
\quad\text{and}\quad
\bar{f_z}(w) = \sum_{i=1}^n i z^{i-1} w[i],
$$
and the problem then reduces to showing that the function
$$\frac{\bar{f_z}(w)^2}{1-f_z(w)^2}$$
is convex in $w\in\mathbb R^d$, such that $\|w\|_1\le 1$.
Numerically I have verified this is true for $n$ up to 4.

**Update 2:**
For any $\alpha\ge 0$, the set of $w$ such that
$\frac{\bar{f_z}(w)^2}{1-f_z(w)^2}\le \alpha$
is the same as the set such that
$\bar{f_z}(w)^2+\alpha f_z(w)^2\le \alpha,$
which is clearly convex, as the function $\bar{f_z}(w)^2+\alpha f_z(w)^2$ is a positive sum of convex functions.

That shows $\frac{\bar{f_z}(w)^2}{1-f_z(w)^2}$ is quasi-convex, which should be enough to prove the original conjecture!

Comment: The notation is a little confusing. You want to minimize $\frac{1-P(z)^2}{P'(z)^2}$ with respect to $x$ and $y$ on the sphere, for a fixed $z$?

Comment: @angryavian You are right. I've updated the statement. Michael Grant, you are right, except the functions are squared.

Comment: Since $x$ and $y$ only appear in product form, I would replace them with a single variable $w$. Then examine the set $\{w\,|\,w_i=x_iy_i,~i=1,..,n,~\|x\|=\|y\|=1\}$ and see if that gets you some insight.

Comment: (That's not a hint, it's a suggestion :-))

Comment: How is this an optimal control problem?

Comment: @MichaelGrant Can we say anything about the shape of this set? I've updated with a proof for the $x=y$ case, which uses that the variable set is convex in this case.

Comment: I don't think it's convex in the $x=y$ case, because $\|x\|=1$ is not a convex set, but $\|x\|\leq 1$ is. However, if you go back to my $w$ variables, it's easy to get $w=0$ if $x$ and $y$ or orthogonal to each other. So maybe the $w$ set is convex.

Comment: I think it's quite possible that the $w$ set is an $\ell_1$ norm ball.

Comment: @MichaelGrant I think you are right! One side follows from Cauchy Schwarz, and surely the interior values are achievable. Combined with the "one variable convexity proof" I believe that completes the proof! If you want to add it as an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: It's OK, go for it!

Comment: I tend to be skeptical of convexity of functions that are not obviously so. There's a lot of wishful thinking that takes place about convexity

Comment: @MichaelGrant Thinking more about it, it's actually the multiplicative inverse of the function I need to be convex, and numerically that appears to be true. Then it's just the question of how to prove it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Lemma: For $n\ge 2$, let $v\in\mathbb R^n$ be a vector with $\|v\|_1\le 1$, then there exists $x,y\in\mathbb R^d$ with $\|x\|_2=\|y\|_2=1$ such that for all $i\in[n]$, $v_i=x_iy_i$.

Proof: We prove the lemma by induction.
For $n=2$ let $x=(\alpha,\sqrt{1-\alpha^2})$ and $y=(v_1/\alpha, \text{sign}(v_2)\sqrt{1-(v_1/\alpha)^2})$.
For $|\alpha|\le|v_1|$ these are unit vectors with $x_1 y_1=v_1$.
We further need $(1-\alpha^2)(1-(v_1/\alpha)^2)=v_2^2$.
This has a solution exactly when $d=(1+v_1^2-v_2^2)-4v_1^2\ge 0$, which is equivalent with $|v_1|+|v_2|\le 1$.
Then $\alpha^2 = ((1+v_1^2-v_2^2)-\sqrt{d})/2\le v_1^2$, which is what we needed.

For $n>2$ let $x_n=\sqrt{|v_n|}$ and $y_n=\text{sign}(v_n)\sqrt{|v_n|}$.
Let $s=\sqrt{1-|v_n|}$.
By induction (and scaling) there exists vectors $\bar{x},\bar{y}\in\mathbb R^{n-1}$ with $\|\bar{x}\|_2=\|\bar{y}\|_2=s$ such that $\bar{x}_i \bar{y}_i=v_i$ for all $i\in [n-1]$, as long as $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} |v_i|\le \|\bar{x}\|_2\|\bar{y}\|_2=s^2$.
In our case we have $\sum_{i=1}^n |v_i|\le 1$ so $s^2=1-|v_n|\ge \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} |v_n|$, which completes the proof.

---

Combined with Cauchy-Schwarz we have proven Michael Grant's conjecture that $\{v : v_i=x_i y_i, i=1\dots n, \|x\|_2=\|y\|_2=1\}$ is exactly the $\ell_1$ ball.

Combined with the proof of convexity of the function given in the question update, we have a complete proof.